# C# - Using the OnStart method to call a thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am building a Windows Service in C#, and I have a method called OnStart, all of my bussiness logic is in a file named code.cs, how can I tell the OnStart method to call the stater method "starter" in code.cs?

```
/// <summary>
/// OnStart: Put startup code here
///  - Start threads, get inital data, etc.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnStart needs to return in order for Windows to know the service is started.  You should launch a new Thread in OnStart that calls your starter.  Something like:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadStarter));
    MyThread.Start();

    base.OnStart(args);
}

private void MyThreadStarter()
{
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.Starter();
}
```

This assumes your current Starter method does not spawn it's own thread.  The key is to allow OnStart to return.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an instance of an object and call the method on the instance.

E.g.

```
CodeMyClass obj = new CodeMyClass();
obj.Starter();

//Replace CodeMyClass with the Type name. or if it is a single call the appropriate constructor.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not right. The Starter() method here should be run on a separate thread, or OnStart() will not return to Windows immediately.